# How to get the font script type from the font

Tags: harfbuzz

I am using harfbuzz to shape regional font and this is my current code.

```
HBShaper2(const string& fontFile, FreeTypeLib* lib, int fontSize);
FreeTypeLib lib;
HBShaper2 hindiShaper("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\mangal.ttf", &lib, (int)fontSize);

typedef struct {
    std::string data;
    std::string language;
    hb_script_t script;
    hb_direction_t direction;
    const char* c_data() { return data.c_str(); };
} HBText2;

HBText2 hbt5 = {
         stdstrTxt.c_str(),
         "hi",
         HB_SCRIPT_DEVANAGARI, // How to get this value of the font
         HB_DIRECTION_LTR
    };
```

Currently i am manually setting the hb_script_t value in the code.

How can i get this value of the font ?

Comment: "*How to get this value from the font*" What makes you think the font knows what script it is? I'm not saying it doesn't. But your question seems very much like asking a jpeg about the contents of the picture it stores.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas i wanted to know how can i get the script of the font.

Comment: And I'm suggesting that fonts probably don't store that information. Fonts store glyphs; exactly what script those glyphs mean or what script they represent may not be encoded in the font file. Much like if you take a picture of a rock, a person could tell you that it's a rock, but there's no metadata in the picture file itself that says this.